# What is the result of making log4j additivity equals to true or false?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In simple terms what is the result of making `additivity="true"` or `additivity="false"` when adding a Log4j configuration for a specific class like this?

```
<Logger name="com.mypage.glass.TryWindow" level="INFO" additivity="true">
  <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
  <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
</Logger>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

By default, a logger inherits the appenders from its ancestors. By setting `additivity="false"`, you prevent this behaviour.

In your example, there may be appenders associated with `com.mypage.glass` or `com.mypage` or even the root logger that would be inherited if you don't set that property to `false`.

Comment: But what happens on the actual file...meaning if i make it true or false what will happen on the outputed log on the file or console?

Comment: @user3433510 Suppose your root logger has a ConsoleAppender configured, so that all INFO messages get printed to the console. If you have `additivity="true"` (the default), your `com.mypage.glass.TryWindow` logger will also output to the console. If you wanted to prevent this, you could set `additivity="false"`. If any of these terms are confusing, I suggest you read the [short introduction to log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: Adding a a property "inheritAppenders" would have been to simple... THX!