# How to exclude a package from root tag in xml configuration log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to disable the logging of a package for certain appenders, but I still have them logged everything else.

I have tried:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console">
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="files">
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <category name="org.springframework.beans">
        <priority value="info" />
    </category>

    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="my.package.to.disable.log" level="off">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="files" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This disables my package logs in both appenders. How could I prevent this?

Comment: Check this question: [What is the result of making log4j additivity equals to true or false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22692097/11748454)