# Logback writes to the console even if ConsoleAppender is not configured

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, logback-classic

I am new to the logging frameworks in java. My code doesn't have any configuration xml file for logback.
code is:

```
public void initilizeLogging(final String logName) {
        final Logger log = lc.getLogger(logName);
        log.setLevel(this.logLevel);

        setupFileLogging(log, this.lc);
    }

private void setupFileLogging(final Logger log, final LoggerContext loggerContext) {
        rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        rollingFileAppender.setFile(this.logFilePath);
      // other settings here..
        rollingpolicy = new SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
        rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingpolicy);

        log.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
}
```

There is no ConsoleAppender is configured, but still I see that the logs are written both to file and the console. How can I stop the logs written to the console? Or where should I look for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able solve this issue by setting:
`logger.setAdditive(false);`

Found the answer here:
[What is the result of making log4j additivity equals to true or false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692097/what-is-the-result-of-making-log4j-additivity-equals-to-true-or-false)
[How to disable Logback output to console programmatically but append to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460684/how-to-disable-logback-output-to-console-programmatically-but-append-to-file)